# transition is not invoked on view-state in spring webflow

Tags: spring

Transition is not invoked in my view-state and when I click the fogotusername link in my login page, it again lands to the login page itself. I think the webflow session is somehow lost. Any idea? Please help.

fogotUsername link in my login.jsp is below:

```
<a href="login.do?_eventId=fogotUsername&page=init" > <spring:message code="label.forgetUsername" /></a>
```

My login flow xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" start-state="login">     


    <view-state id="login" view="tiles.login"> 
        <transition on="fogotUsername" to="viewForgotUsername">         
        </transition>
        <transition on="fogotPassword" to="viewForgotPassword">
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="viewForgotUsername" view="tiles.forgotUsername"> 
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="viewForgotPassword" model="password" view="tiles.changePassword">
        <transition on="submit" to="viewForgotUsername"/>
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="loginend"/> 

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link doesn't contain the flow execution URL. Try replacing your link element with the below:

`<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=fogotUsername"><spring:message code="label.forgetUsername" /></a>`